# How to convert an invalid XML to Valid XML

Tags: xml, xsd

How to convert an invalid XML to Valid XML according given xsd-schema?
For example, I have next xsd schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and next invalid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../my_xsd.xsd">
  <to>reviver@mail.com</to>
  <from>sender@mail.com</from>
  <body>blablabla</body> <!-- IVALID LINE, IT IS NOT IN RIGHT PALCE -->
  <heading>head</heading>
</note>
```

My question is: Do JAXB, XSTREAM, or other XML parsers have solution to convert my invalid XML according given schema to valid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../my_xsd.xsd">
  <to>reviver@mail.com</to>
  <from>sender@mail.com</from>
  <heading>head</heading>
  <body>blablabla</body>
</note>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: I'll assume the input is well-formed XML.

In **general**, the answer is no... no algorithm would be able to convert an **arbitrary** XML input document to a valid *and semantically correct* instance of a given schema.

*However,* if the ways in which the input can be invalid are **constrained** to just a small set of problems, such as child elements of `<note>` being out of order, then **yes**, just about any XML parsing and serialization library could help you fix the problem. As @KevinDTimm alluded to, you'll want to turn off schema validation in these tools so that they don't reject the input before fixing it.

Personally I would use XSLT since that's what I'm used to. You could have it read the child elements in whatever order they occur, and output them as XML in the correct order:

```
<xsl:template match="note">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="to" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="from" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="heading" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="body" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But the example tools you list - JAXB and XSTREAM - are not merely XML parsers, but XML *object* parsers/serializers. If you need to correct validation errors while building an object, that would complicate things. A separate process of correcting, and then deserializing, would be simpler.

Comment: Acctually - yes. I expect to get velformed XML but with element in incorrect order. And main feature that I need  - it is put elements and attributes in right order, acording given XSD.

Comment: @AleksandrZhytnikov: note that the above template is meant to be used along with an identity template (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT). Alternatively, you can replace `apply-templates` with `copy-of`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the items to be reordered, you'll probably have to first read them without the xsd then use xslt to order them to the liking of the xsd.